# Ubuntu 18.04: Authentication is required - no drop down menu in order to select admin user

Tags: 18.04, authentication

We are two admins in the network, and on each computer that we install Ubuntu we have set our own user.
Each PC has the following users: `admin1`,`admin2`,`desktop_user`.

When I try to install something from the "desktop_user" account a popup appear that  has only one admin user, there is no drop down menu in order to select the other admin user.

The PCs are up to date and all have been install from scratch.
version: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I added this picture to see the difference between ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 when the normal user is asked for authentication in order to install/run a program.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGYeK.jpg
In my system there are 2 users that have administrator rights, but i can't select my user because there is no drop down menu in order to select the user.

I hope the picture will clarify what i'm trying to obtain

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit  your question  to expand it with specific details about what you do.